# Retrieve user defined folders with ews

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I can't find documentation over the web about how to retrieve folders created by users using exchange webservice.
I can get all known folders or a folder by name, but i wish to get only inbox and user defined folders.

How to do this without having to compare each folder from WellKnownFolderName enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing against the WellKnownFolderName enum really is the only way to do it. There is no property you can check to see if it's a user defined folder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After hours of investigations and tests, i came to the same conclusion. It's unbelievable that Microsoft don't offer a proper way to do this...